# How to check whether url contains "main.php"

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to know if the URL contains "main.php".
How can I do this in jQuery?

I tried this

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('main.php') > -1 ) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

The full url would be www.flirtwithme.co/main.php

What's the most efficent way to capture the main.php?

Also I'm using hash like this

> http://localhost/flirtwithme.co/main.php#profile

with `$(window).bind('hashchange')`

So how can I capture main.php when it doesn't have a hash value. This is the real question I'm after, as I have hash changing working. I want the URL alone (main.php) to be controllable.

Comment: It seems to me what you really want to do is just capture the hash. There's nothing wrong with using the native javascript methods to do something, in fact it can be quicker as that's all jQuery eventually does behind the scenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if (filename == 'main.php' && window.location.hash == '') // do stuff
```

Comment: this works fine but how can I make it not fire if the URL has a #?

Answer (score 2):

To get the last segment...

```
var lastPathSegment = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

> So how can I capture main.php when it doesn't have a hash value. This is the real question I'm after, as I have hash changing working. I want the URL alone (main.php) to be controllable.

Look into the new methods on the `history` object, such as `history.pushState()`.